# bitwarden as alternative to LastPass?

Tags: password-management

I stumbled over [bitwarden](https://bitwarden.com/), a service that promises to provide a service like LastPass (all data encrypted on your device, but additionally stored on a central server for easy access).

I am not talking about the price tag but about security: does anyone have any insight of the process? Is it really as secure as they claim?

Everything seems to be found in [github](https://github.com/bitwarden), but I am not good enough as far as security goes (and as developer) to come to a decision.

I do not ask for a code review (and of course neither for any form of endorsement), but more for some insight of *"Beware, I looked into it, and it is probably/obviously unsafe, because ..."*

I am trying to formulate my concerns:

- anybody can start such a project and say "we handle it as securely as possible"
- verification of this claim requires a code review, which I cannot expect at this time
- I was hoping someone might already have had a look into the overall organization of the project (i.e. are there any **obvious** flaws?)
- The claims/promises sound a little "too good to be true", especially as they provide hosting of the encrypted data for free
   <sub>We all know "If it sounds too good to be true it probably isn't true"</sub>